# searchguide level3 Hijack on iceweasel

Tags: kali-linux

I have been using Iceweasel on my Kali Linux desktop. I didn't install it from an untrusted source and I only have official links in my sources.lst file. I didn't open any malicious links but my Iceweasel browser is showing search results from searchguide.level3.com.

I have already scanned my system using lynis but there were no alarming results. How can I fix this?

Comment: Did you install any 3rd Party tools or plugins or addons? Did you visit sites with random ads and click on them?

Comment: These are for Windows but you need to follow something similar: http://easyviruskilling.com/remove-searchguide-level3-com-virus-searchguide-level3-com-removal-help/

http://blog.mitechmate.com/searchguide-level3-com-removal/

Comment: "iceweasel" just the name alone makes me want to use Linux instead of Windows....

Comment: I didn't installed any add-on

Answer (score 0):

Select Tools / Extensions / Remove

Uninstall unknown and suspicious extensions like Speed Analysis, BrowserProtect and Webcake.

Comment: There are no addons